# Is it beneficial to use Play framework while JDBC is blocking in nature

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nonblocking, playframework-2.5

I am using play framework with Java in a project. We had a lot of concurrent users, so we decided to rewrite the whole project using play in order to benefit from its non blocking feature to support more concurrent users. The DB behind the project is Oracle and as you know all of the JDBC drivers are using blocking IO except for [ReactivMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/).
I have searched a lot and reached to the conclusion that currently there are no work around to make Oracle JDBC driver non blocking. However Oracle supports non-blocking calls in its native OCI driver (Unfortunately it is based on polling instead of callback or interrupt) There are not even experimental projects! This proves that the need is not felt yet and it must have a reason. Off course I found the following link which is a [my-sql asynchronous connector](https://code.google.com/archive/p/async-mysql-connector/wikis) for Java but nothing for Oracle.

This brings me to my question. Is it really beneficial to use Play framework while I have a blocking JDBC driver for Oracle?

Comment: See [slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/introduction.html#reactive-applications).

Comment: It seems that slick improves performance and is resilience under load but still your DB calls are blocking. By the way can I use slick in java projects?

Answer (score 0):

Use background thread for JDBC connection and communicate with this thread via messages.

Honestly, *nobody* uses OCI in non-blocking mode. It has various non-documented limitations. And some OCI calls unpredictably switch the library back into blocking mode. On the other hand OCI is quite safe to be used from multi-threaded environment.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you handle it since it blocks another thread in another location or server. Your cpu is still wasted where it's not needed (IO).

Comment: Then a thread is sleeping(waiting for response from DB), no resources are wasted.

Comment: Actually the thread being idle is currently our problem. According to the concept of non blocking threads must not remain idle they must be released so that they can handle other requests.